# Firebug 1.6 bug

Tags: firefox, firebug

Is it possible to fix this bug without downloading an older verson of it?

When I click on the search text field on top right side, it keeps on blinking.

Comment: I remember seeing some blinking in the Firebug console, and it seems to have gone away on the newest build on the 1.7 branch. https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.7X/ so you could try that and see if it works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, to fix a bug you just need the buggy version installed. Then go to the Firebug plugin  directory and fix the bug directly in the source.

If you do not want to do this check if your bug has already been reported in their [bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list), if not report it there and wait for a fixed release.